# Java creating json from translation key value pairs

Tags: java, json, list

I have a sorted list (by key) of key value pairs like this:

```
administration.edit.error.type1 = val1
administration.edit.error.type2 = val2
administration.edit.success.type1 = val3
administration.label.button.close = val4
administration.label.button.edit = val5
home.label.button.open = val6
```

I would want to convert this list to

```
{
    "administration": {
        "edit": {
            "error": {
                "type1": val1,
                "type2": val2,
            },
            "success": {
                "type1": val3
            }
        },
        "label": {
            "button": {
                "close": val4,
                "edit": val5,
            }
        }
    },
    "home": {
        "label": {
            "button": {
                "open": val6
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The provided input list is unknown, as well as the levels connected by the dots** 
My approach would have been to recursively, iterate through the list and create JsonNodes with Jackson mapper. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Is there maybe a library that can already do this?

Comment: Are the values of any particular type? Or just anything?

Comment: They are just strings.

Comment: In that case, you might be able to implement a simple parser using JsonNodeFactory and creating an Object when you see a `.` and a string when you see `=`.

Comment: I will give it a shot, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaPropsMapper, from [jackson-dataformat-properties](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/properties) does the job

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsMapper;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("/tmp/test.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(fr);

    HashMap map = new JavaPropsMapper().readPropertiesAs(properties, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println(map);

    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
    System.out.println(json);

  }
}
```

Output for your sample-file:

```
{administration={edit={error={type2=val2, type1=val1}, success={type1=val3}}, label={button={close=val4, edit=val5}}}, home={label={button={open=val6}}}}
{"administration":{"edit":{"error":{"type2":"val2","type1":"val1"},"success":{"type1":"val3"}},"label":{"button":{"close":"val4","edit":"val5"}}},"home":{"label":{"button":{"open":"val6"}}}}
```

The sample uses these dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-properties</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
```